# Select from table based on count

Tags: sqlite, select, count

I have table like this:

```
id | name | type
-----------------
 0 | firs |    2
 1 | secs |    3
 2 | this |    9
 1 | thus |    3
```

I know id (it is not unique id) and type and I want to select records only if there is specified number of records with that id and type.
For one record I tried for example this:

```
select * from myTable
where
(select count(*) from myTable where myTable.id = 0 and myTable.type = 2) = 1;
```

This returns me all rows, not just the one row I want. Can anyone please tell me, what is the right way how to get the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where statement looks like WHERE 1 = 1 and it's always true so SELECT gets every column from your table.
If you want select for example data where id = 1 and type = 3 and number of occurrences = 2 you can do something like that:

```
select * from myTable
where
(select count(*) from myTable where myTable.id = 1 and myTable.type = 3) = 2 and myTable.id = 1 and myTable.type = 3;
```

Comment: You are right. I forgot that it is inner select so I have to add columns conditions also to the outer one. Thanks.